# How to get image file while serialize the form in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Yamaha", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreateBikeForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

 {

    <input type="file" name="file" id="jsonimage"/>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Image, new  { type="file"})
 }
```

this script:

```
var serializedform = $("#CreateBikeForm").serialize();
$.post("/Yamaha/Register/", serializedform, function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

In this searialized form does not contain the image property.

Comment: and what do you expect in the result?

Comment: what should the serialized content for file field be?

Comment: Try var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

Comment: I did not get the file while serialize the form.

Comment: How to pass image file while form serialization. I did not get Image property while serialize the Form @Zazu